Where to get the kernel module wlan.ko from?
For a project that I'm currently working on, I had to recompile the Linux kernel 4.4.0-148-generic under Ubuntu 14.04. For this purpose, I followed a guide that allows me to first create the kernel as a Debian package on a more powerful machine and then roll it out to the target platform.
This has worked so far without any problems. However, I need the kernel module wlan.ko, because it has to be given a parameter during the loading process. However, I can't find this kernel module on the target platform. The following commands did not yield a hit:
lsmod | grep -i wlan
modinfo wlan
find /lib/modules/4.4.0-148-generic/ -name "*\*wlan\**"

so that I'm conclulding that wlan.ko does not exist on my target platform.

I have already found a comparable post that deals with the missing kernel module wlan.ko. However, this post didn't help me so far.
Another post is also asking about where to find the missing wlan.ko module. However, the given answer seems to be tied to another platform and didn't help me out.

For this reason, I would like to know if I missed an option in the kernel configuration using make menuconfigor if I can create the wlan.ko module differently?

Could it be built-in? In that case follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035110/passing-parameter-to-builtin-kernel-module-at-compile-time

You may be trying to follow obsolete instructions. If wlan.ko is supposed to be the general WiFi subsystem, CONFIG_WLAN is a Boolean kernel configuration option in 4.4.x series, i.e. you can either have it built-in to the kernel, or not at all; there is no option to build it as a module. If it's supposed to be a driver for a particular WiFi chip, it's probably been renamed to something more chip/vendor specific since the instructions you're using were written. What's the parameter you're trying to specify for it?

@ArtemS.Tashkinov: I'm assuming that wlan.ko is neither a kernel module nor build into the kernel itself. To check if wlan.ko is directly build into the kernel, I executed "cat /lib/modules/4.4.0-148-generic/modules.builtin | grep -i wlan", however got no positive feedback

@telcoM: My documentation states that I must load the wlan kernel module according to "insmod wlan.ko con_mode=5" to enter the FTM (Factory Test Mode). The wifi module uses the QCA6174 chip that uses the ath10k driver. I am unsure whether "con_mode=5" can be passed to the corresponding kernel moduels (ath10k_pci, ath10k_core, ath, mac80211, cfg80211).

Googling for insmod wlan.ko con_mode=5 brings me to a Github discussion about a kernel specifically patched for Xiaomi Leo devices. In that patch, the driver is in drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/. In a generic Ubuntu kernel, this patch is probably not included and so the driver would not exist. It seems it might be this driver.

@telcoM: Thanks for the hint! I cloned the mentioned repository and also executed the corresponding makefile to apply the patch to my current kernel. However, I'm getting several "implicit declaration of function" errors during compilation. Could you possibly give me a hint how to resolve this issue?

It's been at least 4 years since the qcacld-2.0 repo was last updated, so the code probably needs some maintenance. You would need to verify that the "implicitly declared" functions still exist in the kernel and have the same sets of parameters as expected by the code. With luck, you might need to only update some #include statements to match the current location of the function prototype declarations; but if the function parameters have changed, you might have to modify the driver code to match.
